# Variables within my function become undefined when I try to nest the function inside an object

Tags: javascript

So I'm very new, and I apologize if the solution can be found easily. If that is the case then I don't know how to ask the question properly.

While studying Javascript I thought it would be fun to write a simple memory game using Javascript for my kids. My initial scripts.js file worked up to the point that I could shuffle an array of number pairs and reveal the corresponding picture by using an event listener:

```
//initialize game by shuffling pairs and then assigning contents of array to game squares
//start with neat pairs
images = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18];
randomImages = [];
//populate randomImages array
randomImages.length = images.length;

function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
//call shuffle
randomImages = shuffle(images);

//assign images to corresponding image paths in /images
imagePath = []
imagePath.length = images.length;

for (i = 0, max = imagePath.length - 1; i <= max; i++) {
    imagePath[i] = "images/" + randomImages[i] + ".jpg";
}

//when clicked show image in corresponding square
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var clickNum = 0;
    var imgNum2 = 0;
    var imgId2;
    e = e || window.event;

    //determine which part of the document was clicked and replace image on    the fly
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        imgId = target.id;
    if (clickNum < 2) {
        imgNum = Number(imgId.replace(/[a-z]*/g, ""));
        document.getElementById(imgId).src = imagePath[imgNum - 1];
        clickNum++;
        imgNum2 = imgNum;
        imgId2 = imgId;
    } else if (imgNum === images[imgNum]) {
        console.log("will add point");


    } else {
        document.getElementById(imgId2).src = "images/question.png";
        document.getElementById(imgId).src = "images/question.png";
    }

}, false);
```

This was getting messy though, so I tried to tidy up by rewriting the code and using an object to contain most of the game data:

```
var gameData = {
    images: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18],
    imagePath: [],

    reveal: function(e) {
        var clickNum = 0;
        var imgNum2 = 0;
        var imgId2;
        e = e || window.event;
        //determine which part of the document was clicked and replace image on the fly
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
            imgId = target.id;
        lastId = imgId;
        imgNum = Number(lastId.replace(/[a-z]*/g, ""));
        if (clickNum < 2) {
            document.getElementById(lastId).src = gameData.imagePath[imgNum - 1];
            clickNum++;
            imgNum2 = imgNum;
            imgId2 = lastId;
        } else if (imgNum === gameData.images[imgNum]) {
            console.log("will add point");


        } else {
            document.getElementById(imgId2).src = "images/question.png";
            document.getElementById(lastId).src = "images/question.png";
        }
    }
}

function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}

shuffle(gameData.images);

for (i = 0, max = gameData.imagePath.length - 1; i <= max; i++) {
    gameData.imagePath[i] = "images/" + gameData.images[i] + ".jpg";
}

document.addEventListener('click', gameData.reveal, false);
```

I realize I probably didn't have to paste all of the code, but I'm lost now as to why the reveal function stops working and why the variables return undefined when I try to troubleshoot. I think it may be a scope issue but I have spent a lot of time looking up the possible answers I think of and not really getting an understanding of what broke the code. The shuffle function is supposed to be in the object as well, but I've made a mess trying to pinpoint at what point I lose functionality of the variables within gameData.reveal().

Comment: Is `gameData` getting undefined inside `reveal`? if yes, you should use `this` instead.

Comment: @Rajesh I believe `e` is the culprit, I don't know if the window event is being passed to reveal properly.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you will receive event. Try consoling it. Also will need a working demo to be precise, but you should always use `this` in current scope. You current logic will fail if you have multiple objects of `gameData`. Also you might have to use `gameData.reveal.bind(gameData)`

Comment: you will have to use `.bind`. When you assign eventListener, `this` will point to that element and not your object. So you will have to change the context of `this` [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/wkdkynry/)

Comment: @Rajesh It seems that setting `gameData.imagePath.length = gameData.images.length` and changing `this` in the `if` statement within `reveal()` back to `document.getElementById(lastId).src = gameData.imagePath[imgNum-1];` has gotten it working. Weird, I still don't know why but at least it's working. Did I misread your bind comment? Would bind have done the same thing? Either way thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Yes. Bind would update the context to the passed object.